# Zend Framework 2 Form Fieldset Error

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2, fieldset

I'm learning ZF2 and trying to create a form but whenever i run the url that calls the form action i get the following message:

```
Zend\Form\Fieldset::add requires that $elementOrFieldset be an object implementing Zend\Form\ElementInterface; received "string"
```

My stack if the following:

> #0 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(179): Zend\Form\Fieldset->add('location', Array)
>
> #1 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/module/Application/src/Application/Form/Info.php(69): Zend\Form\Form->add('location')
>
> #2 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php(25): Application\Form\Info->__construct()
>
> #3 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Application\Controller\IndexController->infoAction()
>
> #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #5 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #6 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> #7 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #8 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
>
> #9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #10 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #11 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> #12 /Users/cesar/Documents/zf2course/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #13 /Users/Cesar/Documents/zf2course/public/index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
>
> #14 {main}

I create the Form class like this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class Info extends Form
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
      parent::__construct('info'); 
      
      $location = new Element('location');
      $location->setLabel('Location');
      $location->setAttribute(array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'class' => 'form-control',
      ));
      
      $sizeW = new Element\Number('size_w');
      $sizeW->setLabel('Width Size');
      $sizeW->setAttributes(array(
                'min'  => '0',
                'max'  => '500',
                'step' => '0.1', 
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ));

      $sizeH = new Element\Number('size_h');
      $sizeH->setLabel('Height Size');
      $sizeH->setAttributes(array(
                'min'  => '0',
                'max'  => '500',
                'step' => '0.1', 
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ));    
      
      $type = new Element\Select('plot_type');
      $type->setLabel('Plot Type');
      $type->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
      $type->setValueOptions(array(
          1 => 'Balcony',
          2 => 'Plot',
      ));

      $family = new Element\Number('family');
      $family->setLabel('Family Aggregate Number');
      $family->setAttributes(array(
                'min'  => '0',
                'max'  => '10',
                'step' => '1', 
                'class' => 'form-control'
      ));
      
      $diff = new Element\Select('diff');
      $diff->setLabel('Gardening Type');
      $diff->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
      $diff->setValueOptions(array(
          1 => 'Begginner',
          2 => 'Advanced',
      ));
      
      $submit = new Element\Submit('submit');
      $submit->setValue('Submit');
      $submit->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
      
      $this->add('location');
      $this->add('size_w');
      $this->add('size_h');
      $this->add('plot_type');
      $this->add('family');
      $this->add('diff');
      $this->add('submit');
    }
}
```

And I called the infocontroller with the form like so:

```
...
   public function infoAction()
    {
        $form = new Info();
        
        if ($this->request->isPost()) 
        { 
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
            // save stuff

        }
        
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
        ));
    }
```

Am I missing something or did I needed to create this fieldset class and that's why it's giving me this error?
Also if anyone has some good zf2 tutorials to send me that would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why these lines with string parameters:

```
  $this->add('location');
  $this->add('size_w');
  $this->add('size_h');
  $this->add('plot_type');
  $this->add('family');
  $this->add('diff');
  $this->add('submit');
```

as you just define all the elements before in variables? Try to replace them by these variables:

```
  $this->add($location);
  $this->add($sizeW);
  $this->add($sizeH);
  $this->add($type);
  $this->add($family);
  $this->add($diff);
  $this->add($submit);
```

For your question about ZF2 Tutorial, the [offical one](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/overview.html) is a good one, did you tried it ?

Comment: Guess i was reading the tutorial wrong.
I was also following that tutorial but it got kinda confused to me.
Maybe ZF is too advanced for me at the moment but i'm trying. 

That did the trick and was able to make the form work. Thanks